# Symfony 4: use localizeddate

Tags: php, symfony4

I am trying to use `localizeddate` to show a date in French on my website:

```
<td>{{ saison.start|localizeddate('medium', 'none') }}</td>
```

I followed the various documentations and:

- I installed the PHP Intl extension: `sudo pacman -S php-intl`
- I installed Twig extensions on Symfony: `composer require twig/extensions`
- As well in Intl extension: `composer require symfony/intl`

I also edited `config/services.yaml` to change the locale, but it does not seem to have an effect:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'fr'
```

I enabled Date and Intl extensions in files `config`packages\twig_extensions.yaml`:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: false
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    # Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension
    #Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: ~
    Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: ~
    Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: ~
    #Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: ~
```

But I still have the date shown in english in the output file.

I also tried to specify more clearly the locale in `localizeddate` like this:

```
<td>{{ saison.start|localizeddate('medium', 'none', 'fr') }}</td>
```

But in this case I get an error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter::__construct() method's argument $locale value 'fr' behavior is not implemented. Only the locale "en" is supported. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.").

I don't know what is missing.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: No not really. I used instead: `<date variable>|date('d/m/Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter name has changed.
You should now use `format_datetime` provided by the `twig/intl-extra` package.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format_datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

As I did not find a correct answer, this is how I solved the problem (As I don't need international support):

```
<date variable>|date('d/m/Y')
```

This is not satisfactory as `localizedate` is done exactly for this purpose, but in the meantime it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the PHP intl extension was not installed correctly, as the `symfony/intl` only works with the `en` locale.

> The replacement layer is limited to the `en` locale. If you want to use other locales, you should [install the intl extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php). There is no conflict between the two because, even if you use the extension, this package can still be useful to access the ICU data.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

If you look up the `__construct()` method for `Symfony\Component\Intl\NumberFormatter` you can see why your code raised this exception:

```php
if ('en' !== $locale && null !== $locale) {
   throw new MethodArgumentValueNotImplementedException(__METHOD__, 'locale', $locale, 'Only the locale "en" is supported');
}
```

https://github.com/symfony/intl/blob/v4.0.0/NumberFormatter/NumberFormatter.php#L262